# how to add a new button near the create button in the form view in odoo 15

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

**Hello everyone!**
I'm currently working on customizing a form view in Odoo, and I'm facing an issue while trying to add a custom button next to the 'Create' button. I've attempted to use  expressions and different positioning methods, but unfortunately, it's not working as expected.

Here's the code snippet I've tried so far:
[code snippet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16h1t.png)

Although this code snippet works, it places the custom button inside the form instead of next to the menu button. The button appears within the header section of the form. However, my goal is to have the custom button positioned directly beside the 'Create' button in the form's header.
I also tried using  as follows, but it resulted in an error since the button couldn't be located:
[code snippet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lou4m.png)

Comment: What's the reason for placing the button next to the "Create" Button? It is much more complex to implement this requirement instead of leaving the button directly in the form header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the [FormView.buttons](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/legacy/xml/base.xml#L644) template to add your custom button and override the [render_button](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/views/form/form_controller.js#L175) function to add the click (
Extend the `FormView` and use `js_class` on the `form` tag)

**Extend the web template:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates>

    <t t-extend="FormView.buttons" t-name="My.buttons">
       <t t-jquery="button.o_form_button_create" t-operation="after">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary custom_button">
               Custom Button
           </button>
       </t>
   </t>

</templates>
```

**Create a custom form controller:**

```js
/**  @odoo-module **/

import FormController from 'web.FormController';
import FormView from 'web.FormView';
import viewRegistry from 'web.view_registry';
import core from 'web.core';
var qweb = core.qweb;


var CustomFormController = FormController.extend({
    
   _ExecuteCustomAction: function () {
       
   },

   renderButtons: function ($node) {
        var $footer = this.footerToButtons ? this.renderer.$el && this.renderer.$('footer') : null;
        var mustRenderFooterButtons = $footer && $footer.length;
        if ((this.defaultButtons && !this.$buttons) || mustRenderFooterButtons) {
            this.$buttons = $('<div/>');
            if (mustRenderFooterButtons) {
                this.$buttons.append($footer);
            } else {
                this.$buttons.append(qweb.render("My.buttons", {widget: this}));
                this.$buttons.on('click', '.o_form_button_edit', this._onEdit.bind(this));
                this.$buttons.on('click', '.o_form_button_create', this._onCreate.bind(this));
                this.$buttons.on('click', '.o_form_button_save', this._onSave.bind(this));
                this.$buttons.on('click', '.o_form_button_cancel', this._onDiscard.bind(this));
                this.$buttons.on('click', '.custom_button', this._ExecuteCustomAction.bind(this));
                this._assignSaveCancelKeyboardBehavior(this.$buttons.find('.o_form_buttons_edit'));
                this.$buttons.find('.o_form_buttons_edit').tooltip({
                    delay: {show: 200, hide:0},
                    title: function(){
                        return qweb.render('SaveCancelButton.tooltip');
                    },
                    trigger: 'manual',
                });
            }
        }
        if (this.$buttons && $node) {
            this.$buttons.appendTo($node);
        }
    },
});

var CustomFormView = FormView.extend({
   config: _.extend({}, FormView.prototype.config, {
       Controller: CustomFormController,
   }),
});

viewRegistry.add('custom_form_view', CustomFormView);
```

**Add the files to the manifest file:**

```py
'assets': {
    'web.assets_backend': [
        "MODULE/static/src/js/form_view_buttons.js",
    ],
    'web.assets_qweb': [
        "MODULE/static/src/xml/form_view_buttons.xml",
    ],
},
```

**Set the `js_class` attribute on the form view tag:**

```xml
<form js_class="custom_form_view">
```